# How to unit test a handler in vert.x java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, vert.x

I have a method that makes a call to external endpoint using `io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient` . I am not able to test the handler method of it. 
This is the method that needs to be tested:

```
public void freshdeskPostRequest(CompletableFuture<ResponseObject> completableFuture, String url, JsonObject jsonObject, String action) {
        webClient.postAbs(url)
                .putHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
                .putHeader(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, freshdeskAuthHandler)
                .timeout(fresdeskTimeout)
                .sendJsonObject(jsonObject, httpResponseAsyncResult -> {
                    getFreshdeskResponse(completableFuture, action, httpResponseAsyncResult);
                });
    }
```

The method in it `getFreshdeskResponse` needs to be tested by making a mock call to the `url`. But the method is called in handler so I am not sure how to mock the call and execute the handler. I checked several answers on the forum as well went through the docs but none of them helped. Please help. I am using `Junit`, `Mockito` as testing frameworks. Please help.

Comment: do you wan't integration test or unit test ?

Comment: @moradi it is unit test. I already mentioned in the question. I need to mock that call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **ArgumentCaptor** of the **mockito** library to capture the lambda expression and trigger the lambda manually. Ex :

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<SomeHandlerType> captor;  // create ArgumentCaptor for handler
```

SomeHandlerType is the type of handler. Then call the sendJsonObject() with captor.capture() like so -

```
mockedRequest.sendJsonObject(captor.capture()); // capture the argument
SomeHandlerType handler = captor.getValue(); // get the handler lambda
handler.handle(dummyResponse);  // trigger the handler manually
```